# Align Baseline of Text with TikZ Picture, before at North, after at East

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

Curious how you'd go about doing something that results in the following with TikZ:

[image]

I thought I'd try something like this:

```
Here is some text to wrap
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift={-\ht\strutbox}]current bounding box.north)}, execute at end picture={baseline=(current bounding box.east)}]
\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
around this picture
```

But surely it just does the former.

PS. as an added plus, if the text on the right side could have the text's mid-height be at the bounding box mid-height, that would be preferred (as opposed to the baseline of the text being at the mid-height of the bounding box given by the "east" setting)

Comment: I am actually not sure what you want to achive. Exactly the same as in the picture? Then I would recommend just to use nodes.

Comment: You have the idea as per your answer below, though I'm looking for something more generic/flexible to apply to any TikZ picture

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
    

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift={-\ht\strutbox}]current bounding box.north)}, execute at end picture={baseline=(current bounding box.east)}]
    \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \node[xshift=-2.2cm] at (0,1.8){Here is some text to wrap};
    \node[xshift=1.8cm] at (3,1){around this picture
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or do you mean to wrap it inside a text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift={-\ht\strutbox}]current bounding box.north)}, execute at end picture={baseline=(current bounding box.east)}]
        \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange!!

I've used this technique countless times. First, draw what you like. Then use the `current bounding box` of what you've drawn **so far** to place text, or anything else for that matter. You can then go on and add more elements if you like, without disturbing what you've already drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %% very handy

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %% Draw anything you like; in this case a simple rectangle:
    \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    %%
    %% Use the current bounding box to place the text anywhere you like:
    \node[inner ysep=0pt,%% Top of text will align with top of current bounding box
        left=0pt of current bounding box.north west,%% Adjust to suit; use tikz positioning library
        anchor=north east
    ] {Here is some text to wrap};
    \node[right=0pt of current bounding box.east,%% Use tikz positioning library
        anchor=west %% Vertically centers the content of the node
    ]{around this picture};
    %%
    %% Now you can draw anything else you like here, for example:
    \node[draw] at (1,-.4) {More stuff};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]